# How to dynamically set table name for every query in go-pg?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I have a bunch of similar temp tables which I am trying to query using [go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg)'s ORM. I can't find a way to dynamically change the queried table during a select:

```
import "gopkg.in/pg.v4"

type MyModel struct {
    TableName struct{} `sql:"temp_table1"`
    Id              int64
    Name            string  
}

var mymodels []MyModel
err := db.Model(&mymodels).Column("mymodel.id", "mymodel.name").Select()
```

This will query `temp_table1` as defined in the model's `TableName`. Is there a way to pass table name as a parameter so I can query `temp_table_X`?

(I can just not use ORM and go with raw `db.Query()`, but I wanted to see if there is a way to use ORM).

Comment: can you get the underlying query that resulted?

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer on [github](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/issues/377#issuecomment-256109421):

```
err := db.Model().TableExpr("temp_table_999 AS mymodel").Column("mymodel.id", "mymodel.name").Select(&mymodels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can [specify the table directly](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/v5/orm/query.go#L92): `db.Model(&mymodels).Table('temp_table1').Column("mymodel.id", "mymodel.name").Select()`

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried that, it seems to add this table on top, not to change the core table. The resulting sql is `SELECT "mymodel"."id", "mymodel"."name" FROM "mymodels" AS "mymodel", "temp_table1"`